# How to delete duplicates from structure array with int and string components

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

In my project I have

```
struct Cities{public int Name;public int n}
```

`int n` represents the population of a city.

I also have `cities[] c;`, that array will be filled with names and number of citizens in city.

Example:

```
c[0].Name="New York";c[0].n=845698;
```

I need to write a method that will erase all cities from the array which have same names (if there is some) and to add their population to first one.

Comment: Just think how you would do it manually, and automate that: for each city, put it in another structure; see if there are duplicates in the original structure. If there are, sum their populations and add them to the new structure; then delete them from the original structure so you don't have to "look" at them anymore. Keep going until there is nothing left in the first structure.

Comment: First an array is real bad choice as you cannot delete a row from an array and even new you need to know the size up front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
    struct Cities
    {
        public string name;
        public int n;
    }

    [Test]
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Cities[] c = new Cities[7];

        c[0].name = "new york";
        c[0].n = 10;
        c[1].name = "detroit";
        c[1].n = 20;
        c[2].name = "las vegas";
        c[2].n = 30;
        c[3].name = "new york";
        c[3].n = 40;
        c[4].name = "detroit";
        c[4].n = 50;
        c[5].name = "chicago";
        c[5].n = 60;
        c[6].name = "chicago";
        c[6].n = 70;

        c = c.GroupBy(ct => ct.name)
            .Select(cl => new Cities
            {
                name = cl.First().name,
                n = cl.Sum(ct => ct.n)
            }).ToArray();

        foreach (var city in c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"city={city.name}, pop={city.n}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could save yourself a little bit of overhead by replacing `name = cl.First().name` with `name = cl.Key`.

Answer (score 0):

If the situation is just as simple as you describe, you might want to consider a

```
Dictionary<string, int>
```

You would then never add a duplicate city, rather if the city already existed (use trygetvalue(key, out value) or something) you would simply add the population.

Otherwise you are stuck with a simple search to find duplicates, and a routine which combines the duplicates and removes one of them.

Comment: Well I need to input name and population from .txt file to array, so i don't know if this would work. Also I'm not familiar with Dictionary